# How can I fix the "the application was unable to start correctly (0x000007b)” error while opening WampServer?

Tags: wampserver

How can I fix the "the application was unable to start correctly (0x000007b)” error while opening WampServer?

i have installed all the redistributable of Microsoft but still the error remains. need help !! :(

Comment: Are you using a 64bit Windows and the 64bit WAMPServer?

Comment: If so, you still must install all the 32bit MSVC Runtmes as well as the 64bit runtimes as among other things wampmanager.exe is still a 32bit program

Comment: Anything to say?

Comment: yeah..i have installed 32bit as well as 64 bit redistributables ,But i got my problem solved when i installed 2012 redistributable update 4

Comment: Right, so not all the Redistributables were installed